# firebase security api read permission denied

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I found a neat little example for permission based chat rooms using firebase security api [here](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/4741111)

Notice the `"chat": {
     // the list of chats may not be listed (no .read permissions here)`

I actually need to list the chats a user belongs to when I load their inbox, however I can't seem to get the `.read` rule correctly.

Ive tried using the following rule which makes total sense but doesn't work:

```
 "convos": {
     ".read" : "auth != null && data.child('users').hasChild(auth.id)",
```

I suspect the problem is that there is still a level between convo and users.. aka would make more sense to do:

```
 "convos": {
     ".read" : "auth != null && data.child($key + '/users').hasChild(auth.id)", 
     $key : { ... }
```

But that's not allowed is complains about $key not existing yet.

How can I allow a user to pull all the convos they belongs to using this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use security rules to filter data. Generally, your data structure will be fairly dependent on your specific use case--most directly on how the data will be read back.

A general solution is to list the chats your user belongs to separate from the bulk chat data, i.e. to [heavily denormalize](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html), and access the chats individually.

```
/messages/$chat_id/... (messages chronologically ordered using push() ids)
/chats/$chat_id/... (meta data)
/my_chats/$user_id/$chat_id/true (the value here is probably not important)
```

Now to access all of my chats, I could do something like the following:

```
var fb = new Firebase(URL);

fb.child('my_chats/'+myUserId).on('child_added', function(snap) {
   var chatID = snap.name());
   loadChat(chatID);
});

function loadChat(chatID) {
   fb.child('messages/'+chatID).on('child_added', function(snap) {
      console.log('new message', chatID, snap.val());
   });
}
```

You would still want security rules to validate the structure of chat messages, and access to a users' chat list, et al. But the functionality of filtering would be done with an index like this, or by another creative data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure how you're structuring your Firebase, but this might work:

```
 "convos": {
     $key : {
      ".read" : "auth != null && data.child('users').hasChild(auth.id)",
      ... 
     }
```

Comment: that doesnt seem to allow me to read a list of convos , as mentioned in the comment of that code